# Converting hex to int while reading a text file

Tags: string, algorithm, c#-4.0, hex

I have few hex numbers that the last digit mean the length of the string after. for example 
2E3F00004Sara
41590000AFavhilmnfr
Except from:
**515900016Mickael Barrie Linwood**

Which is 22 not 16.. 
any idea how to get it from the number? 
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, `16` is right since `16` is hexadecimal representation for decimal `22`:

```
16 in hex = 1*16 + 6 = 22
```

You could convert an hex string to an int number with this in C#:

```
int namelength = Convert.ToInt32("0016", 16);  
// namelength will be 22
namelength = Convert.ToInt32("000A", 16);  
// namelength will be 10
```

Comment: right, thank you. there is a simple way to convert it to int in c#?

Comment: This is the simple way: `int n = Convert.ToInt32("0016", 16);`